# ORM for .net Without Linq

Tags: .net, orm

I'm looking for ORMs that dosent support linq, i have a huge database more than (150 tables) I can't use linq To Sql or Entity framework cuz the database is not very well structured. i'm in the a process of refactoring so i'm looking for an ORM that uses old fashion SPs and entity mapping any suggestions ?

Comment: Exactly why can't you use L2S or L2E? And doy you mind if the orm has its own LINQ provider?

Comment: The question makes no sense - that the database is not well structured does not preclude use of Linq, though it may make it rather less pleasant. Futher it seems to me that its almost inherent in EF that you can deal with a poor db structure in the mapping layer.

Comment: L2S and L2E use Keys for traking updates, i think that u dont know that :), so the structure of the database is very important when using Linq To sql or Linq To entities. which is not my case. i cannt use these tools cuz i my database is not well structured... after all my question is what ORM is the best other than linq to sql or entity framework ...

Comment: Any reasonably regular ORM will **need** primary keys and foreign keys - if your database is a mess - clean it up! Don't just plaster a layer over it to hide the mess....

Comment: the database is on production, contains valuable data. i'm writing a new module and then i will redactor the old ones, my question was as simple as i need ORMs other than L2S and L2E no more.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) might work pretty well for you.  You can edit its T4 templates all you want to highly customize what's available on your entities and repositories, and the stored procedure support is pretty good (for what I needed on my project, anyway).  Besides stored procedures there's also a decent fluent syntax for constructing additional queries in the code, but if you're concerned that those won't work well you can simply not used them (or potentially even disable them).

As for "not supporting LINQ" you could simply not use that feature, surely?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use Entity Framework 4. You almost can do everything with the model and use T4 templates to refactor code in your needs. Generate POCO classes or what suits your needs.
Self tracking entities or let the model generate the code by default. Supports 1 on 1 table - entity mapping and inheritance, supports complex properties that you can create for your domain. I think these should be enough to get you work.

You could also use eSQL commands instead of Linq 2 Entities, so avoids linq queries, though i can't see any reason doing that??? LINQ it's just great..

Comment: the database has no Keys in it, as i asked before it is not well structured, L2S/ L2E. just dont update any data. you need to use PKs at least, which is not my case

Comment: EF requires keys for each entity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the following steps:

1) Download [Entity Developer for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper) tool

2) Create [LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect) model using the Database First wizard

3) Generate classes for your application using T4-like templates. Modify these templates if you need some code generation customization

4) Go to model classes and implement extensible methods that override your CRUD operations. At this step you can provide support of stored procedures in the persistence layer.

Comment: thx, I've downloaded the free version and I'm trin it now. thanks so much...